# Check .HasValue and .Value for Nullabe of T

Tags: c#

I've need to do some refactoring and I came across to this:

```
if(LoanTerms.RateIncreasable.HasValue && LoanTerms.RateIncreasable.Value) { ... }
```

and `LoanTerms.RateIncreasable` is of type `System.Nullable<bool>`

So I'm wondering do I need `.HasValue` check on this? Will `null` be treated like false in if statement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the default of `bool` is `false` you can use this code which does everything you need:

```
if(LoanTerms.RateIncreasable.GetValueOrDefault()) { ... }
```

For more information, look at the documentation at [MSDN: Nullable(T).GetValueOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx).

But to answer your question: It is not legal to read the `Value` property of `Nullable<T>` if the `Nullable<T>` value is `null` (ie. `HasValue == false`), you'll get an exception. So if you absolutely must read `Value`, ensure it has a value first.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will handle your issue.

```
if(LoanTerms.RateIncreasable.GetValueOrDefault()) { ... }
```

If you call `GetValueOrDefault` it checks if `HasValue` is `true` or `false`:

```
public T GetValueOrDefault(T defaultValue)
{
    return HasValue ? value : defaultValue;
}
```